# Android - Print multiple images

Tags: android, image, printing

Is there a way to print multiple images on Android without selecting the Printer for each image (or presenting the OS Printing UI)?

I am interested in both pre Printing Framework and also using the Printing Framework.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android#integration-steps

By looking at the documentation it doesn't seem so, but maybe I am missing something.

Thank you,
Cosmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to create a multi-page pdf that contains the images that you'd like to print. This [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html) has details on how to connect to the Android print manager and get your content ready for printing. In particular, you can look at [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#draw-content) which shows how you can use a `PdfDocument` object to create a pdf page by page from a bitmap.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I've ended up doing.